# Type mismatch: inferred type is data class but Int was expected

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm fetching data from API. But I'm facing a problem, the LazyColumn items is not accepting the state vairable. I have this error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Weather? but Int was expected

code:

```
  @GET("/v1/forecast.json")
 suspend fun getWeatherInfo(
    @Query("key") apiKey:String = API_KEY,
    @Query("q") country:String
):Weather


 suspend fun getWeatherInfo(country:String):Weather{
    return weatherApi.getWeatherInfo(country = country)
}



private val _state = mutableStateOf(WeatherState())
val state: State<WeatherState>
    get() = _state

data class Weather(
    @SerialName("current")
    val current: Current,
    @SerialName("forecast")
    val forecast: Forecast,
    @SerialName("location")
    val location: Location
)

LazyColumn{

    items(state.weather){

    }
```

Any help?

Comment: What is WeatherState class?

Comment: It's just a sealed class that I initialize the Weather variable in it. Though it serves no purpose here but I used to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are using wrong method. You should consider not using LazyColumn, as you probably do not need it, but if you do, it would be something like this:

```
val mutableState = mutableStateOf(WeatherState())

@Composable
fun LazyListWeather() {
    LazyColumn {
        item {
            Text(text = mutableState.value.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

But IMO you do not need. You have only one Weather item. Just use simple column, if you do not have list of WeatherState

Comment: Thank you very much. It's my mistake, I've never considered that it's just one column.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need/want to use LazyColumn then make sure to:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).